# Linked list in python statement comfusion

Tags: python

I am implementing linked list in python and I came across two statements and confused now

While displaying elements 
I used a statement

```
p=self.start
While p.link is not None:
    Print p.info
    p=p.link
```

Like in my list if there are 1  2 3 4 5 then 
It's printing only 1  2 3 4 5

But if I use

```
While p is not None:
    Print p.info
    p=p.link
```

It's printing 1 2 3 4 5 which I want 
So what's the difference between 
While p.link Is not None:  And  While p Is not None:

Comment: `p.link is not None` checks if the *next* item is still none, so the above will stop before the *last* node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a linked list, the `p.next` (or here `p.link`) refers to the *next* node. In case we reached the end of the linked list, then the next node is `None`.

In your first code fragment, you thus each time check if there is a next node. Only if there is such next node, you will print the current node. This thus means that you will *never* print the last node, since for that last node, `p.link` will be `None`, and hence the `while` loop will stop.

That is not the case in the second example. We here keep iterating until we have reached the end of the list and `p` now is `None`.

Note that the former will raise an error in case the linked list is *empty*, since in that case `p.start` is `None`, and thus has no `.link` attribute.

Comment: When we use p is not none exactly which part of the node it checks for info part or link part

Comment: @HemantChauhan: no part at all, since that means that the previous node had `None` as `.link`, and `p` is thus not a node, but just `None`.